# How to remove Gmail from iPad mail?

Tags: ipad, email, gmail

During iPad setup I configured Gmail as email on iPad, now I want to remove Gmail from my iPad email, how to do it?

Comment: Can you please leave the edits, the idea is to keep the spelling consistent across the whole site. And even Apple calls it **iPad**...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the "Settings" app

1. "Mail, Contacts, Calendars".
2. Tap on your Gmail account
3. In the dialog that comes up tap the big red "Delete Account" button at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Will this delete my gmail account

Comment: @Gee no. It will just remove it from your iDevice.

Answer (score 1):

go to settings and in the mail section you will see your email account, in the bottom there is a delet button, this is for remove your current email