# Removing a given email synced to my iPad?

Tags: ios, mail.app, data-synchronization, gmail

I set my work gmail account to my *personal* iPad and now I don't have that job.  Since email is not coming in I can assume that either my PW changed or my account was closed from the business or IT.

But now ... can I remove it from iPad or am I stuck with this archived onto my iPad?

ALSO ... If I remove it from the iPad does the business retain access elsewhere?

I saw this and found it similar but not as specific: [How to remove Gmail from iPad mail?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58606/how-to-remove-gmail-from-ipad-mail)

Any takers?  Mine is similar but connected to a business.  Any info or links would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to be done with all trace of the mail, simply fire up your iPad and go to the settings app.

From there, tap on **Mail, Contacts, Calendars** and select the mail account in question.

The Delete Account control will remove that account and all messages, contacts, calendars and notes that were synced to your work gmail account.

This does nothing to the actual google account and deletes no messages or contacts from the server. That would need a working connection and/or you to log in to the account at http://gmail.com or the URL they set up for your business log in.